# Deploying MVC application framework version issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

I am trying to deploy a new MVC application without any additional libraries installed for testing purposes.  I am getting the following error message:

*Parser Error Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, ''). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.*

```
Line 22:    <customErrors mode="Off" />
Line 23:     <authentication mode="None" />
Line 24:     <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 25:     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 26:   </system.web>
```

I have checked the IIS 7 server manager in Application Pools and the highest framework version I can change to is 4.0.3019.  I have googled around and found that v4 should still work with the application target framework of 4.5.

I don't understand why am I getting this error.  Can anyone suggest a workaround please?

Comment: That hasn't been the case in my experience. Have you tried either setting it to the one you actually have or installed 4.5?

Comment: Is .net 4.5 installed on the server?

Comment: No, I did not want to install as there some other apps hosted.  Should or do I need to install 4.5?  I thought if app targets 4.5 it should still work with 4 on IIS.  Or this is not true?

Comment: It works after installing .net framework 4.5

Comment: No, You are misunderstanding the difference between the runtime version, and framework version.  .NET 4.5 Framework requires the .NET 4.0 runtime (which is what you see in the app pool version).  You still need 4.5 installed if your app is targeting 4.5